# Mat select options showing behind the Dialog

Tags: angular

I have a mat-select object that I use in the Angular dialog, but as you can see in the picture, the data in this object appears behind the dialog, how can I solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXE7.png)

Comment: You need to provide some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a css issue. Somewhere z-index property is being used either in the dropdown or the popup. Please check.